# Example of a ring with exactly one invertible element

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

As the title states, can you please provide an example of a ring with exactly one invertible element? If you make a distinction between rings and unitary rings, then please consider unitary rings only. Please try to come up with the most trivial example you can find.

This is supposed to be a very easy task, but I cannot think of anything.

Comment: You might want to look at some very very small rings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z$$

If you want an infinite ring
$$\mathbb Z/ 2 \mathbb Z [X]$$

**Note** In any ring $\pm 1$ are invertible. A necessary condition for your question is that $1=-1$.

Comment: Thanks. The second statement from your note was an eye-opener.

Answer (score 1):

The [zero ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_ring) only has one element which is therefore its own multiplicative inverse

Comment: I thought of that, but in my book it is required that 0 is not equal to 1. Sorry for not mentioning this in the question itself.